# How to make my jquery plugin not restart when pressing links in my dynamic php website?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a classic php controller that gets the page name from the url and displays that page under my header section where my slideshow lives.Every time a press a link the slideshow restarts from the fisrt photo again or its killed while sliding and image.I know that the cause of that is that everytime time a  link is given to the browser all the page is beeing proccesed again .
  I know a few ways to go arround the problem using Ajax but the only problem with that is that the url will not change because it will be Async..I want to keep my url so my visitors are able to share the links they want.
  An example site is at http://sounds.beatport.com where you press a sample to play , it loads it at the top and then you can browse thru the styles drop down menu changing links but yet the sample keeps playing..

So what i want to achive is having a div with my slideshow plugin keep playing at the top of my site without restarting while the visitors browse thru the site;

Comment: example site uses ajax. There are numerous plugins will help you work with url changes like `jQuery BBQ` or `history.js`

Comment: Probaply history.js is the thing i am looking for...i tried before to put a fake url using javascript but i didnt like the hasktag(#) in the url...thank you for your time !